# what is the meaning of tapply(x,index) if no FUN?

Tags: r, tapply

I know the meaning of `tapply(dat$sale,list(dat$year,dat$province),sum)`in the code:

```
 > dat=data.frame(  
 + year=c(rep(2007,5),rep(2008,3),rep(2009,3)),  
 + province=c("a","a","b","c","d","a","c","d","b","c","d"),  
 + sale=1:11)  
 > tapply(dat$sale,list(dat$year,dat$province),sum)  
       a  b  c  d  
 2007  3  3  4  5  
 2008  6 NA  7  8  
 2009 NA  9 10 11
```

what is the meaning of `tapply(dat$sale,list(dat$year,dat$province))` if there is no FUN in it?

```
> tapply(dat$sale,list(dat$year,dat$province))
[1]  1  1  4  7 10  2  8 11  6  9 12
```

it is a subscripts ,what is the meaning of `12` or `9` in the result?
in which rule can i get `12` or `9`?how to calculate it?

Answer (score 8):

From `?tapply`:

> FUN    the function to be applied, or NULL. In the case of functions
>   like +, %*%, etc., the function name must be backquoted or quoted. If
>   FUN is NULL, tapply returns a vector which can be used to subscript
>   the multi-way array tapply normally produces.

`FUN` defaults to `NULL`, so you get the subscripts.

Note that in R matrices/arrays, like those returned by `tapply`, are just vectors with dimensions.  Matrices are [column-major by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859215/switching-row-major-to-column-major-dimensions), so you will get the `i`th element of the first column until it wraps around to the second column:

```
> mat <- matrix(seq(9),ncol=3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> mat[4]
[1] 4
```